# What file contains the Laravel version info?

Tags: laravel, github

I'm looking at cloning a project from Github, but the readme.md file doesn't include what version of Laravel it's built on.

How can I see what version it is, without pulling it down and running `php artisan -v`?

Is there a specific file in a directory that contains it? (I'm guessing it's where the artisan command looks?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant `VERSION` in [`Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L32) tells you what version they are running.

```
class Application extends Container implements ApplicationContract, HttpKernelInterface
{
    /**
     * The Laravel framework version.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const VERSION = '5.6.26';
```

If the project is using Composer, check for the `laravel/framework` requirement in the `require` rule in `composer.json`.

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.6.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok. So in the Github Repo it is under `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php`. Thanks.